# How to overload and return multiple types with a C# async method?

Tags: c#, async-await, overloading

I want a bunch of `GetDataAsync()` methods which are overloaded to return various data sets based on the type needed. If the function weren't async, I could overload based on `out` parameters:

```
public void GetData(int userId, out int age, out string name) { ... }
public void GetData(int userId, out string name, out string address) { ... }
```

But `out` isn't allowed for `async` methods. Next, I tried using generics to overload (I changed `string` and `int` for other types, since this trick wouldn't be valid for sealed classes):

```
public async Task<Tuple<TName, TAddress>> GetDataAsync<TName, TAddress>(int userId)
    where TAddress : Address where TName : Name
{ ... }
public async Task<Tuple<TAge, TName>> GetDataAsync<TAge, TName>(int userId)
    where TAge : Age where TName : Name
{ ... }
```

But I gather template specialization doesn't really exist in C#, so these are considered to be the same function.

The ugly hack that does enable this overload is passing in buffers which the function populates:

```
public async Task GetDataAsync(int userId, int[] id_output, string[] name_output)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    id_output[0] = 60;
    name_output[0] = "Freddy";
}

public async Task GetDataAsync(int userId, string[] name_output, string[] address_output)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    name_output[0] = "Freddy";
    address_output[0] = "Elm Street";
}
```

But that hack has a bad API. (It would be a little safer using a list as a buffer.) Is there any proper C# way to get different data types from an async overload? If I must, I'll incorporate the datatypes into the function names instead of overloading, but that seems needlessly verbose. And since the functions abstract database calls, some of them would have very long names indeed! (These functions will mostly have more than one caller, hence the desire to define them centrally rather than in the class they're called from.)

Comment: I don't think `GetData` is a great name to begin with. Doesn't every method that provides some form of output get data? Are they really so strongly related that they *should* have the same name? To my eyes, they don't seem to.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Each method gets two or more pieces of data from the database (part of a single row), and initializes each (normally a deserialization from JSON). To my mind, the methods are substantially similar.

Comment: @piojo - But probably not to someone who is given your code and is told to consume it. It's too generic. Surely they have a more specific purpose.

Comment: Having separate method names of `GetNameAndAge` and `GetNameAndAddress` would be *much* clearer IMO.

Comment: And I'd prefer not to have names like `GetInventory_Heroes_BattleData_SceneData()`. I would have to fire myself.

Comment: @DaisyShipton That works, but gets nasty with more than two items. It's a possibility.

Comment: Have you tried to return different types? Either `Task<DataA..B..C.. etc> GetData(int userId)` or using C#7 return tuples and deconstruction.

Comment: @Sinatr A function isn't allowed to be differentiated only by the return type, otherwise this wouldn't have been an issue.

Comment: I don't mean to use overload.. overloads are limited to type, so if you have to pass same combination of types you are in trouble anyway (and have to use different method name anyway). It seems you simply want to return multiple data, that's what I mean ( it should be `GetDataX`).

Comment: @Sinatr I see. You mean return all the data instead of trying to return just some of it depending on what the caller needs? It's an option, but for a game server (users may leave if there is lag), unneeded computation is a liability.

Comment: Note that even if you *could* do this, it immediately falls apart if you have two values with the same type. Suppose "age" and "score" are both of type `int` - how do you differentiate between "fetch the age and name" and "fetch the score and name"?

Comment: @DaisyShipton It's actually all custom classes backed by JSON, so the differences should be clear to the caller and the compiler. Refactoring for normalization is a task for later (or never), since this isn't a data-heavy program. The logic isn't very relational.

Comment: How much does it matter to you that the overload is chosen at compile-time? If you were to have a single (public) generic method that then filled in the right values at execution time, would that be good enough? You wouldn't get compile-time errors if you used a combination that wasn't supported, but it would otherwise work. I'd write it as an answer, but it'll take a while to write up, and I don't want to waste time if compile-time validation is a must-have. (If only *your* code will be calling this, and it's all unit tested, that may not be an issue.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Unfortunately I'm counting on autocomplete to make the API easy to use or extend, so I'm too strongly in favor of static typing. Thank you anyway for the proposed solution.

Answer (score 2):

`out` parameters were created for returning multiple values but they don't work with asynchronous methods because the real method returns before the conceptual method ends execution.

That's why [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tuples) were added to the language.

Tuples represent a loosely related set of values. They are not intended to represent an database raw, an entity or anything that has its own meaning/concept.

Arrays are not a good choice either because you can't guarantee nothing about arrays as method parameters and they are not, for this purpose, strongly typed at all.

What you seem to be looking for is [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/generics):

```
Task<Response> GetAsync<Request, Response>(TRequest request);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work if `TRequest` is not a unique type (for example, a username and auth token). But if I can stuff the return type information into `TRequest` such as `Request<PlayerInventory, BattleData>`, it may work.

Comment: When I do this, I create the Request/Response pair. Usually the Response type derives from a base class for exactly purposes like the ones you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The typesafe and relatively clean solution was inspired by Paulo Morgado's answer. The `Request` class wraps the former parameters, which couldn't be used for overloading because they were always the same--a user ID and token. The unused type parameters serve only to distinguish `Request<Foo, Bar>` from `Request<Foo, Quux>` in the compiler's eyes.

```
public class Request<T1, T2>
{
    // Common data needed by every GetAsync(), no matter what it returns:
    public string user;
    public string token;

    public Request(string user, string token)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.token = token;
    }
}

public class Request<T1, T2, T3> : Request<T1, T2>
{
    public Request(string user, string token) : base(user, token) { }
}
```

The methods can then be overloaded, and each can be made to return the type that corresponds to the request. (The functions must be written manually, but their usage is type-safe.)

```
public async Task<Tuple<UserInventory, UserHeroSet>> LoadAsync(
    Request<ServerUserInventory, UserHeroSet> request)
{ ... }

public async Task<Tuple<UserInventory, BattleData>> LoadAsync(
    Request<UserInventory, BattleData> request)
{ ... }
```

The methods are used as follows:

```
var dbTuple = await LoadAsync(new Request<UserInventory, BattleData>(user, token)).ConfigureAwait(false);
dbTuple.Deconstruct(out UserInventory inventory, out BattleData battleData);
```